# How do I yank the next 4000 chars, ignoring linebreaks?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard

I can for example, copy three lines to the clipboard with `"+y3j`. But I nothing happens when I attempt to yank chars to the clipboard with, say,`"+y100l`.

Ultimately, I want to copy chunks of 4000 chars.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
:set whichwrap+=h,l
```

Then you should be able to yank characters, spanning lines.

Unfortunately this has the side effect of having the <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> able to "wrap" across lines if you use them at the beginning/end of a line, so you may want to do this instead:

```
:se whichwrap+=<,>
```

Then use the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow keys in your key sequence instead of <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd>.

I don't know why your `"+y3l` doesn't work, as it should work just fine, and works for me.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. I was wrong to say "+y3l didn't work. As your answer suggests. It didn't work merely for any number of chars that would go beyond the next newline following the current char position.

Comment: ah. except it doesn't seem to quite work. Just did "+y100> and got 498 chars. Did "+y5000y and got 8597 chars. whichwrap is set =b,b,<,>

Comment: That is, did: "+y5000> and got 8597 chars. (where < and > are right and left arrow-keys)